# d3.js symbol instead of circle

Tags: d3.js, geometry, symbols

I am using below code to create SVG circles, and is working fine.

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
.attr("r", 1e-6)
.attr("id", function(d) {return d.name; })
```

Now I want to use custom symbols instead of circles. I have these symbols in bmp files.

Please guide me on how to do this.

Thanks
Krishna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642) is exactly what you are looking for:

The interesting code is:

```
nodeEnter.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico") //should work with bmp
    .attr("x", -8)
    .attr("y", -8)
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 16);
```